# What is the difference between Robot Resource File and Robot Test Suite in Robot Framework

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, selenium, robotframework

I'm working on Robot framework using python. I integrated that with my Eclipse IDE using RED plugin which is available at market place. My question is, when I created my robot framework project there are resourcefile.robot and testsuitefile.robot in it. But both of them containing same tabs and everything looks like same. What is the basic difference of it. Can you please explain and add some referral links if possible. Thank You.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eNag.png)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A resource file is pretty much the same as a test suite except that it can't have test cases. There are a few other small differences. The main purpose of a resource file is to act as a container for a set of reusable keywords.

From the [robot framework users guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-files):

> The higher-level structure of resource files is the same as that of test case files otherwise, but, of course, they cannot contain Test Case tables. Additionally, the Setting table in resource files can contain only import settings (Library, Resource, Variables) and Documentation. The Variable table and Keyword table are used exactly the same way as in test case files.

Answer (score 0):

Another point to add is when the user tries to add a Test Case section in the Robot Resource File a file content mismatch message pops up. So if the user proceeds further by accepting the changes then that file would be recognized as-as tests suite file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22760775)

Comment: This was something which was not included by the person who answered the question so i have added. Unfortunately, you didn't understand that.